# How to redirect login based on user role

Tags: laravel, redirect, laravel-7, laravel-authentication

I want to redirect the user based on whether he or she is an admin or not.

**LoginController**

```php
protected function authenticated(Request $request, $user)
{
    if ($user->type == 'user') {
        return redirect()->intended('/user');
    } else{
        return redirect()->intended('/admin');
    }
}
```

However, it does not work. Even if the user is a regular user, it redirects to the `/admin` page. I think it's because of the RedirectIfAuthenticated.php but I have no idea how to change it.

```php
public function handle($request, Closure $next, $guard = null)
{
    if (Auth::guard($guard)->check()) {
        return redirect('/admin');
    }

    return $next($request);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In the LoginController.php file that gets generated when you run `php artisan make:auth`, there is a property that handles this, `$redirectTo`.

```php
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

Remove this property and add a method with the same name.

```php
public function redirectTo()
{
    // Your code
}
```

The `redirectTo` method will supersede the `redirectTo` property and allow us to define the custom logic to handle users with different roles to different paths.

```php
public function redirectTo()
{
    $role = auth()->user()->role;

    if ($role === 'admin') {
        return redirect(route('admin'));
    }

    return redirect(route('user'));
}
```